# How to set ggvis to use canvas renderer by default?

Tags: r, ggvis, shiny

Is it possible to make a ggvis widget use the canvas renderer by default (instead of svg)?

Comment: Reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `renderer` to `canvas` in `set_options`:

```
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  set_options(width = 300, height = 200, 
              padding = padding(10, 10, 10, 10),
              renderer = "canvas")
```